# Быстрая пакетная вставка уникальных значений в таблицу mariadb

Tags: python, mysql

Как правильно реализовать быструю пакетную вставку уникальных записей в таблицу mariadb?
Хотелось бы избежать вставку в цикле с проверкой на наличие существующей записи по полям (pair, datatetime, action, price).

К примеру в таблице table1 есть записи

```
pair, datatetime, action, price 
eth/btc, 2020-01-01 20:30:10, sell, 0.1
```

Требуется сделать пакетную вставку

```
eth/btc, 2020-01-01 20:30:10, sell, 0.1 (не вставлять, пропустить поскольку есть запись в table1)
ltc/btc, 2020-02-01 20:35:10, buy, 0.5
eth/btc, 2020-01-01 21:30:10, buy, 0.1
ltc/btc, 2020-02-01 20:35:10, buy, 0.5 (не вставлять, пропустить поскольку запись в table1 появиться при ставке 2 записи)
```

Ожидаемый результат

```
pair, datatetime, action, price 
eth/btc, 2020-01-01 20:30:10, sell, 0.1
ltc/btc, 2020-02-01 20:35:10, buy, 0.5
eth/btc, 2020-01-01 21:30:10, buy, 0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# в коде использована pymysql
data = [
    ['eth/btc', '2020-01-01 20:30:10', 'sell', 0.1],
    ['ltc/btc', '2020-02-01 20:35:10', 'buy', 0.5],
    ['eth/btc', '2020-01-01 20:30:10', 'buy', 0.1],
    ['ltc/btc', '2020-02-01 20:35:10', 'buy', 0.5]
]
db.cursor.executemany(
    "insert ignore into table1 (pair, datatetime, action, price) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
    data
)
```

Answer (score 0):

В случае mysql и maridb нужно использовать оператор ignore при вызове insert into

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/